# Reading a big xslx file in r

Tags: r

I am trying to read a big excel file with almost 30000 rows and 6000 columns.

I have tested `XLConnect` and `XLSX` package, but I get java I/O error:

```
java.io.IOException: ZIP entry size is too large
```

How can I read such a big xlsx file in r?

Comment: Convert it to .csv - IMO the best solution to read in big excel files is not to read excel files...

Comment: I cant convert it to CSV too :/

Comment: Are you using 64-bit R and 64-bit Java?

Comment: No, I am using 32 bit

Comment: Why can't you save the Excel sheet as a csv?  If you're getting an error there, the problem may be a corrupt workbook, not a java error.

Comment: I noticed that it's faster to import .xls files compared to .xlsx

Comment: See [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/read-excel-files-from-r/) for a list of things to try. Also, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963393/out-of-memory-error-java-when-using-r-and-xlconnect-package) for two waya to deal with Java problems associated with XLConnect. The bottom line is this though: if you have a large Excel file and can't read it: *convert to csv*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the memory available to java in the options (in R). Typically like this:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")
data <- read.xlsx(filepath)
```