# In R: How do i solve "Out of memory" error in POS tagger?

Tags: r, twitter, opennlp, pos-tagger, semantic-analysis

In R, i have a data with 30 records for sample, main data has 20000 records. records are tweets. 
I extract bigrams from any tweet and i use from postagger. For sample data,that shown me errors

> .jnew("opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel",
>   .jcast(.jnew("java.io.FileInputStream",  :
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

or

> .jnew("opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel",
>   .jcast(.jnew("java.io.FileInputStream",  :
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

How do i solve this peroblem?

My code is :
    how do i solve this peroblem?

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(data1))
{
 .
 .
 .

 for(k in 1:length(bigrams))
 {
   s = as.String(bigrams[k])
   sent_token_annotator =openNLP:: Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
   word_token_annotator = openNLP::Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
   a2 = annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
   pos_tag_annotator = openNLP::Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()
   a3 = annotate(s, pos_tag_annotator, a2)
   a3w = subset(a3, type == "word")
   tags = sapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS")
   if(tags[1]=="JJ") 
    {
      if(tags[2]=="NN"||tags[2]=="NNS")
      {
        bigram_final[j]=bigrams[k]
        j=j+1;
      }
  .
  .
  .
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue usually happens when a script uses rJava in R, and in my case I changed the memory size for JVM to be more capable of processing my script, by adding the following line before loading libraries `options(java.parameters = "- Xmx1024m")` I also added `gc()` right after the package function to release memory. Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153974/how-to-fix-outofmemoryerror-java-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-in-r) for more info.

Comment: I use from options(java.parameters = "- Xmx1024m") but this error did not change. Thank you for answer this question