# Write Excel is not writing 572988 rows in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, data-science

i was trying to write new data frame in R using Write.xlsx.

i have 572988 rows and 25 column

i get this error:

```
Error in .jcheck(silent = FALSE) : 
Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>.jcall(row[[ir]], "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;",   "createCell", as.integer(colIndex[ic] - 1))new("jobjRef", jobj = <pointer:  0x127f6dcb0>, jclass = "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError")
```

RStudio Version 1.1.453

MacBook Pro 2015

Version 10.14

Processor 2.2 core i7

Comment: Try using write.xlsx from the openxlsx package and not from the xlsx package. openxlsx has no java dependencies.

Comment: Isn't asking that many rows from Excel a bit... much? It would seem you're about [half way there](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you get an Java out of memory exception.

Here you find a description how you adjust the memory with the package XLConnect:

["Out of Memory Error (Java)" when using R and XLConnect package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963393/out-of-memory-error-java-when-using-r-and-xlconnect-package)

For a general understanding, see:

https://www.journaldev.com/2856/java-jvm-memory-model-memory-management-in-java

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153974/how-to-fix-outofmemoryerror-java-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1