# Reading Excel date time data into R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, posixct

I have a large data set in Excel (50k rows, 138 columns). 80 of the columns are date/time values which I want to use as POSIXct type in R.

Option 1: Use XLConnect or xlsx with the colTypes parameter.  Fails due to size of the file with heap size errors.

Option 2: Save as csv and read file, but Excel drops the time values when save as CSV.

Option 3: read into R using openxlsx package with the detectDates option.  This loses the time values.

Option 4: read into R using openxlsx package with detectDates=false.  This returns the date/time values as numeric.

This last option seems to be the most viable, but how do I then conveniently convert 80 columns to POSIXct?  I have a vector of classes that I want for each of the columns that would be provided to the colTypes parameter, but now want to apply this in post-processing after reading the data frame.

Comment: option 2 or 4 and `apply(df[, <col1:colN>], 2, as.POSIX, ...)` is what I would do.

Comment: Did you try package `readxl`? I think it's able to read excel dates correctly

Comment: I have had good experiences with the `XLConnect` package

Comment: @docendo discimus Thanks readxl has done the job perfectly.

Comment: @Alex Thanks too.  I was looking for this construct.  Took a bit to work out how to apply but great for future reference.

Comment: @Gary Weissman. XLConnect has great functionality, but I couldn't get round the java heap size problem with this.

Comment: @sch56 try this memory workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963393/out-of-memory-error-java-when-using-r-and-xlconnect-package

Comment: @sch56, you can answer your own question with a small example of the solution you used - for future readers.