# How to import Large Datasets in Revolution R Enterprise or R Studio?

Tags: r

I'm currently using **Revolution R Enterprise Version 7.5**.

I am trying to import a dataset from **Excel into RRE**. Here is my code:

```
library("dplyr")
library("XLConnectJars")
library("XLConnect")

dataset1 <- readWorksheetFromFile(file.choose(), sheet=1, startRow=1, Header=T)
```

When I try to execute this block of code, this is the error I get:

```
Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Is there anyway to get large amounts of data into **Revolution R Enterprise**? Maybe some **RevoScaleR** library function that I can use?

Even help in **R Studio** will do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Out of Memory Error (Java)" when using R and XLConnect package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963393/out-of-memory-error-java-when-using-r-and-xlconnect-package)

Comment: I've all but given up on using java-based Excel readers. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6099243/3576984) for other options.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't used this particular package (`XLConnect`), the error you are getting is because it imports `rJava`.  You need to change the allocated Java heap size using the following command:

```
options(java.parameters="-Xmx4g")
```

That will change it from the default of 512MB to 4GB; you can choose a different value if you like.

You need to run that command BEFORE you load the libraries.  If I were you, I would restart your R session, run that command, and then proceed.

Comment: Note that if you only want to read Excel files, you are usually much better of using [readxl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html). It has much less overhead than XLConnect.