# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: r, memory, heap-memory

In R Studio using R, when trying to join 2 tables which have about 100k `records(DB2 DB)`, getting below error and none of the google solutions worked.

> Error 'in .jcall(x, "S", "getMessage")': 
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Out of Memory Error (Java)" when using R and XLConnect package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963393/out-of-memory-error-java-when-using-r-and-xlconnect-package)

Comment: did you try `gc();
memory.limit(1e+10) ` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem several times, sometimes randomly. 
What helped me so far was using the following command at the beginning of the script **before** loading any other package!

```
options(java.parameters = c("-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-Xmx8192m"))
```

The `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` loads an alternative garbage collector which seemed to make less problems than the standard GC.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using intillij 
On the main menu, choose File. Invalidate Caches/Restart