# R readxl::read_excel failed to open xls file

Tags: r

`readxl_1.1.0`

I'm trying to read the file from this link (US gov website)

https://www.cftc.gov/files/dea/history/dea_com_xls_2018.zip

When I unzip the xls file inside, and read with `readxl::read_excel`, it fails with the error message `failed to open C:\path to file`

I can open the file in excel, save it to csv and read it to R by `fread`, but there are a lot of those files, so that's tedious. By the way, some other xls files downloaded from the same webpage can be read by `read_excel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something odd about the xls file. I think it's because it contains some VBA code.

If you are happy to use `XLConnect` here is an alternative that reads the file.

```
library(XLConnect)
extdir = tempdir()
unzip("dea_com_xls_2018.zip", exdir = extdir)
file = list.files(extdir, pattern = 'xls', full.names = T)

wb = loadWorkbook(file)
ws = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = 1)

dim(ws)
#[1] 11131   126
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Just to mention that answer from this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/7963393/1568919 also needs to be followed to increase JVM memory.